Pandas: Specific Styling with Multi-Index Columns (Tooltips)
Sorry for the horrible code. I'm somewhat familiar with Pandas library but have never styled before, so please excuse any horrible patterns. I'm trying to learn styling, so general tips welcome but I'll keep my questions specific.
The code below produces a styled DF like this:-

Questions:

How could I style the text on a specific row of the multi-index in the columns? I want to make the strings 'North America', 'Europe' and 'Asia' larger, for example. I'm not sure how to access them since the styling seems to be based on HTML and the TH is affecting more than I want it to.

How could I add a tooltip in a couple of specific cells? For example, in (Europe, Monthly, Feb)[KPI JKL] and (Asia, Weekly, WK-04)[KPI GHI]. The documentation for Styler.set_tooltips is suggesting to create a new DF and apply it. This seems difficult to manage: what if I had a report with dozens of KPIs and more weeks, but only a couple of call outs to highlight via tool tips?

Is it possible to add tooltips to the KPI names in the index? For example, if the user hovers over KPI ABC, it would be good to surface the definition for the KPI. From what I can read in the documentation, tooltips cannot be applied to index or headers..?


# Create an empty DF, use MultiIndex to establish columns
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([
                        'KPI ABC', 
                        'KPI DEF', 
                        'KPI GHI', 
                        'KPI JKL']),
                  
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
                      ['Weekly', 'Monthly'],
                      ['WK-01', 'WK-02', 'WK-03', 'WK-04', 'WK-05', 'WoW', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'MoM']]))

# Hacky approach -- using the from_product function of Pandas MultiIndex creates unncessary products, so using the hide function to remove them
s = df.style.format('{:.0f}').hide([
                                ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
                                ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
                                ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
                                ('North America', 'Weekly', 'MoM'), 
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
                                ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

                                ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
                                ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
                                ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
                                ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'MoM'), 
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
                                ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

                                ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
                                ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
                                ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
                                ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'MoM'), 
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
                                ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WoW')], 
    
    axis="columns")


# Highlights the full row the user is hovering over, highlights the specific cell with the given background color
cell_hover = {
    'selector': 'td:hover',
    'props': [('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}

headers = {
    'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)',
    'props': 'background-color: #000066; color: white;'}

global_left_align = {
    'selector': 'th',
    'props': 'text-align: left'}

s.set_table_styles([cell_hover, headers, global_left_align])


# Creates the line borders

s.set_table_styles({
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-right: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s.set_table_styles({
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): [
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid white'},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066'}]
}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

# Center the column headings
s.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'th.col_heading', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}],overwrite=False)



No worries about the code. It was just fine. As you very correctly noted, Styler does not natively support adding tooltips to index or header cells. BUT, there is a workaround you can use to achieve this. One approach is to generate the HTML manually and inject the necessary tooltip information into it.  I suggest you do the following if you want to ignore question 3:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['KPI ABC', 'KPI DEF', 'KPI GHI', 'KPI JKL']),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
                      ['Weekly', 'Monthly'],
                      ['WK-01', 'WK-02', 'WK-03', 'WK-04', 'WK-05', 'WoW', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'MoM']]))

s = df.style.format('{:.0f}').hide([
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WoW')],
    axis="columns")

cell_hover = {'selector': 'td:hover', 'props': [('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}
headers = {'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)', 'props': 'background-color: #000066; color: white;'}
global_left_align = {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'text-align: left'}

s = s.set_table_styles([cell_hover, headers, global_left_align])

border_styles = {
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'}
}

for key, value in border_styles.items():
    s = s.set_table_styles({key: [value]}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s = s.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th.col_heading', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}], overwrite=False)

def larger_headers(val):
    if val in ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia']:
        return 'font-size: 16pt'
    return ''

s = s.applymap_index(larger_headers, axis='columns', level=0)

tooltips = pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
tooltips.at['KPI JKL', ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'Feb')] = 'Tooltip for Europe, Monthly, Feb [KPI JKL]'
tooltips.at['KPI GHI', ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WK-04')] = 'Tooltip for Asia, Weekly, WK-04 [KPI GHI]'

s = s.set_tooltips(tooltips)

s

and this if you absolutely need 3:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['KPI ABC', 'KPI DEF', 'KPI GHI', 'KPI JKL']),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
                      ['Weekly', 'Monthly'],
                      ['WK-01', 'WK-02', 'WK-03', 'WK-04', 'WK-05', 'WoW', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'MoM']]))

s = df.style.format('{:.0f}').hide([
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WoW')],
    axis="columns")

cell_hover = {'selector': 'td:hover', 'props': [('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}
headers = {'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)', 'props': 'background-color: #000066; color: white;'}
global_left_align = {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'text-align: left'}

s = s.set_table_styles([cell_hover, headers, global_left_align])

border_styles = {
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'}
}

for key, value in border_styles.items():
    s = s.set_table_styles({key: [value]}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

s = s.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th.col_heading', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}], overwrite=False)

def larger_headers(val):
    if val in ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia']:
        return 'font-size: 16pt'
    return ''

s = s.applymap_index(larger_headers, axis='columns', level=0)

tooltips = pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
tooltips.at['KPI JKL', ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'Feb')] = 'Tooltip for Europe, Monthly, Feb [KPI JKL]'
tooltips.at['KPI GHI', ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WK-04')] = 'Tooltip for Asia, Weekly, WK-04 [KPI GHI]'
s = s.set_tooltips(tooltips)

html = s.to_html()

tooltips_index = {
    'KPI ABC': 'Tooltip for KPI ABC',
    'KPI DEF': 'Tooltip for KPI DEF',
    'KPI GHI': 'Tooltip for KPI GHI',
    'KPI JKL': 'Tooltip for KPI JKL'
}

for kpi, tooltip in tooltips_index.items():
    html = html.replace(f'>{kpi}<', f' title="{tooltip}">{kpi}<')

with open('styled_table_with_index_tooltips.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(html))


which in both cases returns


Thank you very much! This is great and you have packed several useful patterns for me to learn. Specifically, the better pattern for the borders (very cool), using the function to apply the styling, and leveraging the 'DF.at' pattern to apply specific tooltips.
Do you have any suggestions on Q3 - is it possible to apply tooltips to the index somehow?

@lummers I have updated my answer. If this is what you wanted, remember to mark the answer as accepted so that it disappears from the list of unanswered question. Happy coding!
